# CommandLine error in autoscheduler "Li2018" Halide

Tags: llvm, halide

I want to test the autoscheduler **"Li2018"** on Ubuntu16.04. I exploit `dlopen` to load the `libgradient_autoscheduler.so` to my pipeline (the plugin of autoscheduler Li2018) and build it, but when I ran the executable file, an error has occured:

```
CommandLine Error: Option 'ppc-use-base-pointer' registered more thanonce! LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
```

I cannot understand what is the `ppc-use-base-pointer` and I don't think I have registered more than once. does someone is familiar with llvm? Or does someone met the same problem and have solved the problem? By the way, my `llvm-config is 3.8.0`.

Comment: I don't know LLVM but I think you need to show the commands you use to run LLVM so people know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the README (https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/README.md), you need llvm with version >= 8.0 for Halide to properly run.